Why async does not return control to the caller after hitting await?
I'm trying to understand how async/await works in C#, specifically related to the thread behavior. I've been reading Stephen Cleary's blog post on async and await (https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and one part of the documentation confuses me:

The beginning of an async method is executed just like any other
method. That is, it runs synchronously until it hits an "await" (or
throws an exception).

I have the following code:
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread Id entering Main Method: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await Something_One();
    }
    static async Task Something_One()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread Id entering Something_One: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await Something_Two();
    } 
    
    static async Task Something_Two()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread Id Entring Something_Two: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

The output I'm seeing is:
Thread Id entering Main Method: 1
Thread Id entering Something_One: 1
Thread Id Entring Something_Two: 1

According to the documentation, I expected the synchronous execution to stop at the first await keyword encountered(and maybe continue on another thread), which is await Something_Two() in the Something_One method. However, the output shows that Something_Two also executes synchronously until it hits the await Task.Delay(1000) line.
Why does Something_Two execute synchronously even though it's called from an await expression in Something_One?
I'm trying to understand the rationale behind the thread behavior I'm observing, especially in light of the documentation statement that async methods run synchronously until they hit an await. Could someone please explain what's happening under the hood

Does this answer your question? Understanding async / await in C#

Don't use a console app to teach yourself async await; they don't obviously do anything else while an operation is being awaited. Use eg a WinForms app with a timer on whose tick refreshes a label with the current time. In a button click handler do a Thread.Sleep(10000) and in another button handler do await Task.Delay(10000). The thread sleep will jam the UI for 10 seconds because the same one thread that handles all the events you've written gets blocked by the sleep so it cannot draw their or service the timer tick. In the task delay version the bread saves its state and disappears off..

..back up the call stack to the place where it normally lives when it's not running your code, ie that place where it is processing window messages and other stuff (not jamming the Ui)

The await is placed visually at the left side of the line, so you assumed logically that it is executed first. Actually it is executed after the invocation of the asynchronous method that follows the await. It might become clearer if we rewrite your example like this:
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread Id entering Main Method: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        Task task = Something_One();
        await task;
    }
    static async Task Something_One()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread Id entering Something_One: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        Task task = Something_Two();
        await task;
    } 
    
    static async Task Something_Two()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread Id Entring Something_Two: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        Task task = Task.Delay(1000);
        await task;
    }
}

The above is exactly the same with your example. Now it becomes obvious that all the code will run synchronously until the Task.Delay(1000) is awaited. Then all these methods will return to their caller an incomplete Task. Eventually the main thread of the console application will be blocked until the Task.Delay(1000) task completes, because that's how console applications with async Main entry point  behave (see the docs for details).

makesense now , thank you so much
